# Android Java Annotation in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

In Android: Java I can use the annotations like `@NotNull` or `@NonNull`.
I wonder if there is a way to use them in flutter (the annotations like ones I've mentioned)

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for: https://dart.dev/codelabs/dart-cheatsheet#null-aware-operators

Comment: What purpose would this serve?

Answer (score 0):

Dart has null-aware operators, that can be used like this:

```
x = y ?? z; //will assign y to x, but if y is null, then z will be assigned instead
x ??=y; //if x is null will assign y to it
x?.foo(); //this way you can call a method on an object only if object (x) is not null
```

Also please check this out (about null-safety in Dart): https://dart.dev/null-safety